# Get last element between slashes with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Assuming a string like http://domain.com/aaaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/

I want to use a .htaccess file to get the last element between slashes, in this case ddd.

I am using:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ ?pt=$1 [L]
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([^/]+)/$ ?pt=$1 [L]
```